# How to retrieve IProblem instances from current editor?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I'm writing an Eclipse plugin, and I'd like to retrieve all instances of `IProblem` associated with the currently open text editor. I've tried the following:

```java
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IEditorPart editor = window.getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
if (!(editor instanceof AbstractTextEditor)) {
  return null;
}

ITextEditor textEditor = (ITextEditor)editor;
IDocumentProvider docProv = textEditor.getDocumentProvider();
IDocument doc = docProv.getDocument(editor.getEditorInput());
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS4);
parser.setSource(doc.get().toCharArray());
CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
return cu.getProblems();
```

However, when I run it against the following code in the editor:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;


public class TestClass implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
}
```

It doesn't find any problems. I would expect it at least finds a `MissingSerialVersion` problem. Perhaps I'm parsing the file incorrectly, which might cause this issue. I feel like there should be a way to get the `CompilationUnit` from the editor directly?

**Update:**

If I add a syntax error to the source file and then invoke the plugin, it reports the syntax problem, but not the missing serial version UID. I suspect this is some kind of configuration issue where warnings aren't being reported.

**2nd Update:**

This isn't just restricted to the `MissingSerialVersion` problem. Anything that is a warning, and not an error, is not found by this method. If I change the problem that I want to see to an error in the compiler settings (or even by passing in additional options to the parser making it an error instead of a warning), I still get no joy from the `getProblems()` method with respect to warnings. (It shows actual errors just fine, e.g. if I put an unrecognized symbol in my source code).